# Was this ever taken to production?

Tags: novelty, us5417445

Re: us5417445

This looks like a remarkable invention.  It seems to turn the current thinking of indepenent suspension on its head.

Was this ever put into production?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at google images -- I see [a great deal of cycle frames](https://www.google.com/search?q=cycle+suspension&tbm=isch) with similarities.

However i'm not sufficient a domain expert to determin if it is exactly the same as described in the patent.